# our company is only paying

Tags: grammaticality, tense

Is **is only paying** grammatically correct in the following sentence?

> if you took pictures yesterday, please note that our company **is only paying**
>   for 1 picture per person.  If you need additional pictures, please reach out to Michael directly and arrange for payments.

Comment: It will be well understood, but the company is paying as opposed to doing something else; it's paying for just one picture as opposed to multiple pictures, so a better phrasing is "our company is paying for **only 1 picture** per person.

Comment: @user105719 why the present continuous tense is correct here?

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have answered the wrong question. The present progressive indicates ongoing action that happens now or will continue to happen in the near future. You could cover future time in a longer sense with the future tense: "Note our company **will** pay only for 1 picture." Or with the so-called enduring present: "Note our company **pays** for only 1 picture." The last indicates a long-standing policy.